# как зарандомить трехзначные числа четных сотен?

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

подскажите как мне сделать задать диапазон для генерации чисел четных сотен?

Comment: Приведите пример нечетной сотни

Comment: нужны числа, разряд сотен которых будет четным числом. например число 637 (6-четное число), а число 592 (5 - нечетное)

Comment: Какой разряд? Послушайте, сформулируйте задание точно, без точного ТЗ вы получите один результат - ХЗ... Что именно вам нужно?

Comment: @Harry, по моему ему нужно генерировать случайные трехзначные четные числа(не уверен)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Четные числа, или числа с четной первой цифрой - понять можно и так, и эдак. А значит, на самом деле будет что-то третье :)

Comment: @Harry, я так понимаю, надо чтобы генерировались случайные трехзначные числа, первая цифра которых будет чётной ([2,4,6,8]**), но уточнение необходимо, согласен с вами)

Comment: разряд сотен в сотнях - первая цифра

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Устроит](https://ideone.com/4rXGUW)?

```
rand()%100+(rand()%4+1)*200
```

Comment: да, спасибо. не подскажете как сделать так, чтобы они могли быть не только положительные, но и отрицательные?

Comment: "Дайте воды напиться, а то так есть хочется, что даже переночевать негде..." Я же вас просил - ДАЙТЕ ТОЧНОЕ ТЗ!!! Ну умножьте полученное число на `((rand()%2)*2-1)`, чтоб не возиться...

Comment: спасибо большое! последняя правка была чисто из интереса сделана, так как обучаюсь самостоятельно и диапазоны ну никак понять не могу. Извиняюсь дико за тупняки((

Comment: Если ответ устроил - закрывайте вопрос, приняв ответ (птичка слева от вопроса).

Answer (score 0):

Генерируй любое трехзначное число. Если оно из "четной" сотни (чётносотенец, хаха) , то отнимай/прибавляй 100 (попеременно, иначе будет перекос в результатах). Или не будет.

Comment: Приведите пример нечетной сотни

Comment: @user7860670 зачем мне приводить вам пример? Я и не знаю ‍♂️ а автор вопроса знает, что это означает, этого достаточно.

Comment: Он и так у вас будет, если строго следовать вашим правилам...

Comment: @Harry да, я уже и сам понял.